# How can obtain curvature from the gradient of a rotation tensor?

Tags: rotations, tensors, curvature

I have proper rotation function $R$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$ that yields a $3 \times 3$ tensor $R(x,y,z)$ for every point (x,y,z) in space. If I differentiate this tensor with respect to position (x,y,z), I get a 3x3x3 tensor $T$ at every point (x,y,z).

Now, I know $R$ defines a rotation 'field' in space, and I can  extract a scalar field such as rotation angle, or a vector field such as axis of rotation from $R$. The question is, can I use $T$ to extract a scalar field that represents the curvature at each point? If so, how?

Comment: Why not follow the same procedure that results in the Riemann tensor, namely, have an infinitesimal closed curve and consider the change in the curve's tangent vector as you parallel transport it along the curve back to its starting point?

Comment: afaik, that method is applicable to manifolds, and the curvature tensor obtained is a property of the manifold itself. I cannot make the connection between this problem and riemann curvature (or maybe I misunderstood you).